# Druid runtime properties

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, druid, apache-druid

I have a doubt regarding the runtime properties we use in the druid helm values.yaml.
This is my configuration:

```
  runtimeProperties: |
    druid.broker.http.numConnections=300
    druid.sql.enable=true
    druid.broker.http.numConnections=500
```

What I want to do is that when installing with Helm, if there is a situation where there are two value files and identical values are present, the 2nd value file's content should be used. And with the helper.tpl I tried to append the values. That's why I have two properties with different values.

Using this configuration, will the druid make use of the `druid.broker.http.numConnections=500` or will the druid not work as expected?

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks